How to install and run an UWP app in Windows without internet?
I have been working as an IT admin in an air-gapped environment (where internet is disabled). I used to know that you can sideload microsoft store apps using .appx, .appxbundle, .msixbundle packages using Add-AppxPackage cmdlet in powershell. Now, even though the apps are installed successfully, it doesn't launch successfully. After going into the rabbit hole, I found some clues in the event viewer. What I understand is, it needs to connect to MSStoreAPI to fetch a license key for whatever reason. How to mitigate this issue?
ServicePackageRundownNotificationImpl PsmKey:Microsoft.8624BDCB0667_1000.19041.3218.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe+Microsoft.WirelessDisplay, sid:S-1-5-21-2801844152-737548724-2567778979-1001
Function: ServicePackageRundownNotificationImpl
Source: onecoreuap\enduser\winstore\licensemanager\lib\service.cpp (2366)

Invoking license manager because app not licensed: PFN Microsoft.8624BDCB0667_1000.19041.3218.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe, hr = 0xD0000272
Function: InvokeLicenseManagerRequired
Source: onecoreuap\enduser\winstore\licensemanager\apisethost\activationapis.cpp (400)

Failure Message: onecoreuap\enduser\winstore\licensemanager\lib\service.cpp(2254)\LicenseManager.dll!00007FF93EAD30F5: Exception(2334) tid(19c4) 800704CF The network location cannot be reached. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help.
    [ServiceEnsureLicenseForPackageActivationImpl]

Failure Message: hr: 0x800704cf
Function: ServiceEnsureLicenseForPackageActivationImpl
Source: onecoreuap\enduser\winstore\licensemanager\lib\service.cpp (2254)

Failure Message: hr: 0x800704cf
Function: ServiceEnsureLicenseForPackageActivationImpl
Source: onecoreuap\enduser\winstore\licensemanager\lib\service.cpp (2254)

Failure Message: onecoreuap\enduser\winstore\licensemanager\lib\service.cpp(1616)\LicenseManager.dll!00007FF93EABC1B5: Exception(2333) tid(1e60) 800704CF The network location cannot be reached. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help.
    [PendingRequest::ThreadProc]

Function: PendingRequest::ThreadProc
Source: onecoreuap\enduser\winstore\licensemanager\lib\service.cpp (1666)

Failure Message: onecoreuap\enduser\winstore\licensemanager\lib\applicensemanager.cpp(260)\LicenseManager.dll!00007FF93EABCC1B: Exception(2332) tid(1e60) 800704CF The network location cannot be reached. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help.
    [ApplicationLicenseManager::GetLicenseForInstalledPackage]

Function: ApplicationLicenseManager::GetLicenseForInstalledPackage
Source: onecoreuap\enduser\winstore\licensemanager\lib\applicensemanager.cpp (263)

Failure Message: onecoreuap\enduser\winstore\licensemanager\lib\onestoreapplicensemanager.cpp(124)\LicenseManager.dll!00007FF93EAB187D: Exception(2331) tid(1e60) 800704CF The network location cannot be reached. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help.
    [OneStoreApplicationLicenseManager::GetLicenseForInstalledPackage]

Function: OneStoreApplicationLicenseManager::GetLicenseForInstalledPackage
Source: onecoreuap\enduser\winstore\licensemanager\lib\onestoreapplicensemanager.cpp (130)

Activation for Microsoft.8624BDCB0667_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.WirelessDisplay failed. Error code: The network location cannot be reached. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help.. Activation phase: PLM prepare for activation

